# Verify whether Selection is fragmented

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, range, selection

I'm facing the following Problem:

With Word Interop I access the Selection via Document.Application.Selection.
Then I have to decide whether the Selection is one Block or fragmented (Multiple Selections via CTRL Key) for further proceeding.

The Range Object includes all selected areas (if copied and pasted), its Text Property includes only the last selected area. I didnt found a Property to check whether the Selection is fragmented...

Answer (score 0):

Word is almost certainly fiddling it under the hood when you copy and paste. As far as COM is concerned, the range - and selection - is the last part only. If you call the Copy method, only the last part goes to the clipboard; if you call Delete, only the last part is deleted. I think it is simply not possible via Automation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The funny thing is that via Selection -> Range -> Copy all parts are copied.